# How to improve prediction using Logistic Regression in matlab?

Tags: matlab, classification, logistic-regression

I'm training my using [LRClassifier](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/42770-logistic-regression-with-regularization-used-to-classify-hand-written-digits/content/Logistic%20Regression%20with%20regularisation/LRClassifier.m) for digit recognition. To train I'm using more than 30000 examples from one set, but while testing on another set (2500 images) I'm getting about 75% correct answers. Is it possible to somehow improve the prediction? If not then what classification is better than logistic regression for that problem and is there any easy tutorial for that?

Comment: yeah..depends on what image you are classifying, and the global solution is to use a Neural Network or DNN or CNN - and no, it is not easy, but here is a tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IyB4bxPbmQA&index=16&list=PLiF-6iXXcQqf4J4OJjU7zH1JrNCr29jas @rayryeng 
I knew it would come handy some day :D

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial. I'll try to learn it.

btw. I'm classifying 56x56 MNIST digits.

Comment: oh yeah...I bet everyone is doing that... CNN can get it up to 97% or even higher with the correct settings

Comment: Don't use logistic regression. Use Neural Networks. They're very well suited for this kind of problem.

Comment: Watched the whole tutorial about Neural networks. It was great. Understood almost everything (how it works, formulas, etc.), but didn't manage to write it in Matlab. Layers and derivatives was too much for me. :/ Is there maybe a library for Matlab that let's you train neural network and then use it to predict digits?

Comment: Yes. Check my github page. There's a toolbox called Neural Network Playground where I wrote a class to perform neural networks training. https://github.com/StackOverflowMATLABchat/NeuralNetPlayground. It's stored in the `NeuralNet2` class. There's also extensive help to show you how to use it.

Comment: Thanks. I've managed to create my own neural network with a little help, but it's getting 89.5% on test set and 100% on training set. Changing iterations from 300 to 1000 gave +0.12%. Is there any way I can improve it? What lambda parameter is the best for digit recognition (currently using 0.1)? Or do I need more nodes in hidden layer?